# How to solve a stream_socket_sendto() error in Symfony 3.4 with WAMP?

Tags: php, symfony, sockets, wamp, symfony-3.4

I try to upload an image with a size of 7MO ( 6.99 exactly ) but I have  this error :

> stream_socket_sendto(): A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

I use  Symfony 3.4 and WAMP and here is a part of my configuration:

```
upload_max_filesize: 16M
post_max_size: 16M
memory_limit: 128M
```

I have this error when I try to dump my photo object but when I don't try it, I have this :

```
Code: $file = $photo->getFile();

Output: The file "" does not exist
```

The PhotoType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nom')

            ->add('file',FileType::class)
            ->add('alt');
    }
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: Which of these lines triggers that error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same error, try to modify the php.ini located in C:\wamp64\bin\php\yourPHPVersion directly. In my case that was this config file witch was loaded.

You can run `php --ini` command in your project to know wich file is used

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error while uploading +3mb files on a symfony5 project and using WAMP and I had to change all those values:

```
post_max_size= -1
upload_max_filesize=-1
memory_limit=-1
max_input_time=300
max_execution_time=300
```

on `php.ini`  , `php.ini-development` , `php.ini-production` and on `phpForApache.ini`
to solve that problem.

Note: You can find all thoes files on `C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.21` .